# Where does the Windows 8 Mail App store data?

Tags: windows-8-preview

I was wondering if the Mail App in Windows 8 stores data (E-Mails, Contacts, etc) on local machine? much like WinMail and Windows Live Mail..

If so how can I determine its storage path?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes it does, if you go to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\`, open the folder that starts with 
"`microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps`", open the folders `\LocalState\Indexed\LiveComm` inside that, then select the folder with the email you want to look at, then one folder down you'll see two folders, "Mail" and "People". Select the one you want, and then a few more folders down you'll .eml files for each of it's stored emails/contacts.

Comment: any tip where the settings are stored? Like server and username?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who upgraded to Windows 10..

I had almost finished a (lengthy) draft email when I decided to upgrade from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. After the upgrade, my 'old' email app was gone, and as I opened the new email app my draft was gone.

Fortunately, I found the mail as the most recent .eml file in

C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Packages\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps\LocalState\Indexed\LiveComm........

just as MatthewThepc described.