# How do I import .eml files to windows 10 mail?

Tags: windows-10, import-mail

I have a bunch of ***.eml** files that I need to import in Windows 10 Mail App.

The files were extacted from a Windows Vista PC with a damaged HDD using the command prompt so the option of doing a "clean" export from Windows Vista is not really a option. 
What I have is all the ***.eml** files in a folder on a USB.

I'm not even sure that the Windows 10 Mail app actually stores emails as ***.eml*** because I have received some emails since starting to use Windows 10 and a search for **.eml** files on the whole HDD does not yield any results!

I am running out of ideas...

A search shows the following thread:
[Where does the Windows 8 Mail App store data?](https://superuser.com/questions/449389/where-does-the-windows-8-mail-app-store-data)
But I went to

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps/LocalState
```

and I cannot find an **indexed** folder.
Help anyone?

Comment: Can you import pst into windows 10 mail? If so there are plenty of eml to pst converters around ...